# Uitextfield in uitableview

Tags: iphone

Hii 
I am using one tableview controller having 11 textfields and 1 date picker and 1 picker.
can i save this value in this controller or should I set this values in another controller .

I have seen almost example and they all have two views one for entering textfield and selecting picker value and when we save it it goes back and save all data in another view.
Is This right way????  or I can use only one view????

If i used this in one view then cells clear values when i scroll table... plz help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is based on how you want the screen.. My point is you can keep all the things in the same view itself..

First the picker

Default hide both the pickers. When you select a tableview cell where you want the picker to be displayed, just set the hidden value of that picker to NO to show the picker with a toolbar. Keep the toolbar just above the picker with two UIBarburrons as done and cancel. done is for selecting the current selected value in the picker to display it the tableview and hide the picker again. Cancel to hide the picker again..

For textfield scrolling
Try to create reusable cells so that you can check it and show the textfields according to that while scrolling the tableview..

Comment: Thanks.can you give me example code of picker view with toolbar.

Comment: Its very simple.. In your IB just keep the UIToolbar just above the Picker.. Now add two barbuttons on the toolbar. Now hide both picker and the toolbar using the hidden property. In the code add a object for Picker and UIToolbar and reference it via IB. where you want you can hide the picker and toolbar by setting its hidden property..You dont need complex code for that..

Answer (score -1):

firstly make a variable in appDelegate and then in this file where the picker and table view is commming , save these values in the appDelegate variable, and get the variable data in the another view with the deceleratoin of App Delegate